# Shadcn ui installation broke my nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

After installing Shadcn ui, my application has failed to run. The problem seems to be from the globals.css file.

The portion where the classes are defined.

I am getting the error that the classes in the block does not exist.

When I comment that out, the error becomes bg-background class does not exist.

The application however runs when I comment the entire block out. The theming however does not work in this case.

Comment: You'll need to share more information, errors, screen shots and code for us to help @usman

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.